# Синус методом Горнера и ряды Тейлора

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Задание: реализовать расчет функции синуса(косинуса). Входные данные в радианах.

[Метод Горнера](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) представляет из себя гнездовую процедуру - когда многочлен со степенями раскладывается во вложенные однотипные выражения (рекуррентную формулу).

Ряд Тейлора для синуса представляет из себя [image]

На этих знаниях моя мысль останавливается.

Comment: Так и в чём вопрос? Вот у вас есть функция разложения синуса.. вот и реализуйте этот расчёт..

Comment: Это разложение по Тейлору, мне нужно по Горнеру, сообразить как не могу.

Comment: Дык это. Вот у Вас есть полином. Как известно, метод Горнера — эффективный способ вычисления полиномов. Примените его, ну же! :)

Comment: Вот в этом и проблема) Я просто не понимаю что надо сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите, суть метода Горнера:

Пусть есть полином `a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4`.
Если вычислять его в лоб, то понадобится сделать 4 возведения в степень (т.е. 6 умножений!). Надо просто заметить, что Вы теряете информацию, когда каждый раз возводите икс в степень, начиная с нуля. Давайте вынесем иксы!

[image: картинка]

Это выражение вычисляется *значительно* быстрее [домашнее задание: сами поймите, почему =)].

Answer (score 1):

Ну, для начала запишите это так, чтобы было явно видно, что это полином:

```
a0 = 0
a1 = 1
a2 = 0
a3 = -1/3!
a4 = 0
a5 = +1/5!
…и так далее…
```

В той статье в википедии есть описание алгоритма.. вот там и написано что теперь с этими всеми `a` и `x` делать: вычисляете эти b по очереди и на ходу перемножаете в цикле и получаете значение функции.

Comment: Спасибо kirelagin за форматирование :)

Answer (score 1):

Хорошее дело, школьные задачи. 
Вот примерный ответ:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double x, e;

    double sin (double next, int f, double s) {
        next *= - x * x / ((double) ((f+1) * (f+2)));
        return abs(next) < e ? s + next : sin(next, f+2, s + next);
    }
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x, &e);
    printf("sin(%lf)=%lf", x, sin(x, 1, x));
}
```

Только в качестве школьного ответа рекомендуется представлять после уяснения некоторых шуток этого кода.
(Для нормальной работы например вынесение x из параметров весьма не рекомендуется).